# UIView touchesBegan won't fire when UILongPressGestureRecognizer minimumPressDuration zero

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan

MyView's and ViewController's touchesBegan won't fire if gestures minimumPressDuration is set to ".zero" but whenever I set it to ".leastNormalMagnitude" it does. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let mySuperView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        v.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
        return v
    }()
    
    let mySubview: MyView = {
        let v = MyView()
        v.backgroundColor = .orange
        v.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 250))
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.addSubview(mySuperView)
        
        mySuperView.addSubview(mySubview)
        
        let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:)))        

        gesture.minimumPressDuration = .zero // when it's set to ".leastNormalMagnitude",
                                             // MyView's and VC's touchesBegan fires.

        mySuperView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func tapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("long pressed.")
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touchesBegan in vc") // -> Won't get called.
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
    
}

class MyView: UIView {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touchesBegan in MyViewClass") // -> Won't get called.
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

I guess I can use it with ".leastNormalMagnitude", still I want to know why is this happening?

Comment: What would it mean to press something for zero time? I think it would mean you didn't press it.

Comment: @matt It's for activation time only. I want long press gesture to be fire instantly.

Comment: but that would not be a long press

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the misuse of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for a scenario where `UITapGestureRecognizer` has to be used instead, I will focus on answering the "why" part.

When you set `gesture.minimumPressDuration = .zero`, the long-press gesture gets instantly recognized.

By default, gesture recognizers tend to delay touches in view, and cancel them if they recognize the gesture.

In order to override this behavior, set

```
gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false // to recieve touchesBegan callback even if gesture is recognized
gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false // to not delay touchesBegan callback
gesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false // to not delay touchesEnded callback
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think that UITapGestureRecognizer should be used with instant tap modifications in touchesBegan method? I'm trying to achieve instant touch feedback right away when touch is down.

Comment: You should use either gesture recognizer, or `touchesBegan` callback, not both. If you just need to recognize "touch down inside", then probably `touchesBegan` callback should be enough. That callback will be instantly called if you don't have any gesture recognizers that may prevent it from being instantly dispatched.